# How can I get cache misses in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, caching

I have a table in SQlite that I'm using to cache some data.  I'm totally hung up on writing an SQL query that when given a list of x strings will return a subset y that are not in the table.  I understand I could just query one by one and check for an empty result but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this that returns a nice, neat list of the strings not cached (not in the table).

FWIW I'm using sqlite3 and Python.  The query I've got so far is something like

```
select e from cache where cache.fk = x and e in (a, b, c);
```

which is close but gives the opposite behavior from what I want (it returns values that would be a cache hit).

I also understand that in this case it is slightly inappropriate to use a relational database over a key/value store but even if I were to switch away I'm still interested in seeing how this would be done.

Comment: You could use `not in` instead of `in`, for starters.

Comment: That returns the set of things in the DB but aren't the ones I'm testing for cache hits/misses.  ex If the db has a, b, c, d and I query for not in (a, b, c, x) I get d.  I want a query for cache misses (the query that would return x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a set value of things you're caching and that they come from a table, use `not exists`:

```
select 
    v.e 
from
    vals v 
where 
    v.fk = x
    and v.e in (a,b,c)
    and not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            cache c
        where
            c.fk = v.fk
            and c.e = v.e
    )
```

If you don't have a table of available values and are just throwing some set back, you'd go with a dynamic table, like this:

```
select 
    v.e 
from
    (
    select a as e
    union all
    select b as e
    union all
    select c as e
    ) v 
where 
    not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            cache c
        where
            c.fk = x
            and c.e = v.e
    )
```

Comment: First off, thank you for going above and beyond and giving both examples!  My DB of choice doesn't let you use dynamic tables but I'm sure if anyone else wanders by later and sees this they'll thank you.  If anyone's interested in the SQLite method I created a temporary table and did a mass insert of all the values I'm testing for cache hits.